# How find records having enddate smaller than month and year

Tags: sql-server

I have table employee having id and joiningdate columns  , now i want to create a query which performs this:

1. if i pass month and year then all the records  having joiningdate smaller than or equals to this date(month and year) should be shown.
2. if month is null then month should not be considered and only year should be considered.

Comment: Passed month and year in INT format OR VARCHAR?

Comment: datatype is varchar

Comment: so mean month='Jan' and year='2016' right?

Comment: Yes, month='Jan' and year='2016'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE TheDate < 
   DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(COALESCE(@MONTH,1) AS int) - 1,CAST(CAST(@YEAR as varchar(4)) + '0101' AS DATETIME));
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is the significance of  '0101' in CAST(CAST(@year as varchar(4)) + '0101' AS DATETIME)

Comment: '0101'  is 1st January, a date 20160101 is an ISO format, probably the most reliable string to date conversion

Comment: you are correct, just confirm because OP said: Yes, month='Jan' and year='2016'

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @tblTest AS TABLE 
 (
   Name  VARCHAR(50),
   JoiningDate Date
 )  

 INSERT INTO @tblTest
  Values ('Sandip','11-Feb-2016')
  ,('Jigar','20-Jun-2016')
  ,('Milan','05-Jan-2015')
  ,('Suresh','25-Apr-2015')


Declare @Month VARCHAR(20)='Feb',@Year VARCHAR(4)='2015'
Declare @LastDateOfMonth Date

IF ISNULL(@Month,'')=''
BEGIN
    SET @Month='DEC'
END

SET @LastDateOfMonth=DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST('01-'+ @Month+'-'+@Year AS DATE)) + 1, 0))

SELECT
    *
FROM @tblTest
WHERE   
    JoiningDate<=@LastDateOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
Declare @yourtable table (EmpName varchar(10), JoiningDate datetime) 

 INSERT INTO @yourtable
  Values ('A','10-Jan-2016')
  ,('B','20-Feb-2016')
  ,('C','05-Apr-2016')
  ,('D','31-Dec-2016')

Declare @month varchar(3) = ''
Declare @year varchar(4) = '2016'

select * 
from @yourtable
Where (isnull(@month,'') <> '' and 
(JoiningDate <= (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,cast('01-'+@month+'-'+@year as date))+1,0)))))
or (isnull(@month,'') = '' and (Year(JoiningDate) =  @year))
```